# Equivalency of Probabilistic statements: can one do algebra within $\Pr [ \cdots ] = x$?

Tags: probability, inequality

This question is motivated by the following example:
For some non-negative RV $X$ and real number $v$ the Markov inequality can be stated:

$$ \Pr [X \geq v] \leq \frac{E(X)}{v} $$

or equivalently,

$$ \Pr [X \geq v \cdot E(X)] \leq \frac{1}{v} $$

I cannot understand how these can be logically equivalent? And as a more general question, are there any rules pertaining to one's ability to pull terms out of the $\Pr[\cdots]$ area or put them into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $\mathbb{E}[X]>0$, as otherwise $X=0$ almost surely (in this case the first inequality is true for all $v>0$, but the second is false for $v>1$).

Setting $t=\frac{v}{\mathbb{E}[X]}>0$ and using the first form of Markov's inequality in your question yields
$$ \mathbb{P}(X\geq t\mathbb{E}[X])\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{t\mathbb{E}[X]}=\frac{1}{t} $$
which is the second form of Markov's inequality in your question.

Similarly, one may go in the opposite direction by writing $v=t\mathbb{E}[X]$.